# "http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease is not valid yet" al intentar de utilisar python3.7:buster en mi Dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker

Tengo [un repositorio para una Django webapp](https://github.com/antoinecomp/scentmate) que quiero dockerizar para que esté disponible rápidamente tanto para edición como para producción. Así que, siguiendo [este tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application) sobre una herramienta de CI/CD, lo he modificado un poco:

```
# Dockerfile

# FROM directive instructing base image to build upon
FROM python:3.7-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-recomends
COPY nginx.default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/webapp
COPY requirements.txt start-server.sh /opt/app
COPY .pip_cache /opt/app/pip_cache/
COPY / /opt/app/webapp/
WORKDIR /apt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --cache-dir /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/app

EXPOSE 8020
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
CMD ["/opt/app/start-server.sh"]
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Projects\todowoo\webapp>docker
build -t scentmate .
[+] Building 218.1s (6/17)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                  0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 766B                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                     0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-buster  0.4s
 => [internal] load build context                                     5.8s
 => => transferring context: 255.58MB                                 5.8s
 => [ 1/13] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7-buster@sha256:f970c2  201.7s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.7-buster@sha256:f970c215c7  0.0s
 => => sha256:f970c215c71ae3bffae6074baeaa3c8dd7c0a3 1.86kB / 1.86kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:589fb0d949f342219f5a60f4e7048c370989eb 2.22kB / 2.22kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:091ca59a28e24dd36fd0cbbba0463b2280b755 9.04kB / 9.04kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:c1c8f1c77d6674046d7deb41be1ca07f25c 10.00MB / 10.00MB  15.3s
 => => sha256:82e5f66f5d0e1c97622f33d44fb04efb42bd3 7.83MB / 7.83MB  12.7s
 => => sha256:8f04e8168e3873638397ca4beb7d8484b15 50.44MB / 50.44MB  83.2s
 => => sha256:5095cab277710f0c2883844158323ad986 51.84MB / 51.84MB  102.1s
 => => sha256:ea7fe362a971515971cf53613a30cc82 192.39MB / 192.39MB  188.0s
 => => sha256:475d8710b0a9c611ad4a36359868daba09109 6.15MB / 6.15MB  94.3s
 => => extracting sha256:8f04e8168e3873638397ca4beb7d8484b150eca0d10  3.3s
 => => extracting sha256:82e5f66f5d0e1c97622f33d44fb04efb42bd3562bdc  0.6s
 => => extracting sha256:c1c8f1c77d6674046d7deb41be1ca07f25cb43fd67f  0.4s
 => => sha256:66fbb20adc6c93e22f47136e3431878b06 16.33MB / 16.33MB  120.4s
 => => sha256:3249a5699df47f48c2c43ff1a98f3127f03739bd 232B / 232B  102.9s
 => => extracting sha256:5095cab277710f0c2883844158323ad986c763ffc37  3.3s
 => => sha256:228df49d5b9a6ccc373a551f57fc4dc30b24 2.35MB / 2.35MB  107.8s
 => => extracting sha256:ea7fe362a971515971cf53613a30cc824f94d544272  9.9s
 => => extracting sha256:475d8710b0a9c611ad4a36359868daba091097621da  0.4s
 => => extracting sha256:66fbb20adc6c93e22f47136e3431878b060aad4e91b  0.8s
 => => extracting sha256:3249a5699df47f48c2c43ff1a98f3127f03739bd7bb  0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:228df49d5b9a6ccc373a551f57fc4dc30b2479ecfd7  0.3s
 => ERROR [ 2/13] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -  15.7s
------
 > [ 2/13] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-
recomends:
#5 0.875 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
#5 0.956 Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates In
Release [65.4 kB]
#5 1.167 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9
kB]
#5 1.803 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [790
7 kB]
#5 9.035 Reading package lists...
#5 9.925 E: Release file for http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dis
ts/buster/updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3h 40min
38s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
#5 9.925 E: Release file for http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 39min 6s). Updates for th
is repository will not be applied.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-recomends]: exit code: 100
```

Comprendo que la version "buster" de python no es disponible: que tengo que utilisar entonces?